# How to open Android soft keys with onclick listener?

Tags: android, android-input-method

I have a View that has a button. On the button click, I want the soft keyboard to pop up with numbers. I can use toggleSoftInput, however, I see no way to change the input type.

```
public class TimerOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick( View view ) {
        Context context = view.getContext();

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        imm.toggleSoftInput( 0, 0 );
    }
}
```

How can I toggle the input with numbers only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code will display keypad to you:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
```

However if you want to force the keyboard that appears into being the Number or telephone keypad, then you have to set the input type on that particular view/widget.

```
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER; 
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE;
```

eg.

```
your_edit_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Credits: Ritesh Gune
[InputMethodManager show numpad in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988897/inputmethodmanager-show-numpad-in-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763900/how-can-my-android-app-programmatically-display-the-keyboard/9764641#9764641) answer:

set inputType to your EditText to "number"

To show the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your view in XML to a number:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

that should force the keyboard to be numeric.